# Using super capacitor with Li-ion battery to power an automated guided vehicle

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, supercapacitor, energy-harvesting

I have an automated guided vehicle which is powering by a 11.1V, 25C, 6000mAh Li-ion battery. The reason I am attempting to make a hybrid power source to power the automated guided vehicle is to prolong the Li-ion battery life by using a super capacitor to provide the transient power to the automated guided vehicle in event such as the starting of the electrical motor (inrush current occurred) and harvest the electrical energy generated during braking of the automated guided vehicle.

The figure attached below is my draft circuit, where the power switching between Li-ion and supercapacitor is done by controlling MOSFETs. For solely usage of the Li-ion battery to power up, only S1 will be closed the rest of MOSFETs remained opened; during braking , S2 and S3 will be closed while S1 opened to create a path to harvest braking energy to the supercapacitor. When the vehicle requires high current, S1 and S3 will closed, both the Li-ion battery and the supercapacitor will power the vehicle as the voltage provided to the motor driver will be the sum of the Li-ion battery's and supercapacitor's voltage.

[image: draft circuit of hybrid system]

I'm new to designing power circuits.  Is the draft workable? How should I do the calculation for the sizing of supercapcitor?

Comment: Exactly which battery is it? What is the maximum expected current draw?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I have seen such a circuit proposed in the scientific literature. In theory it should work. The reason it has not been implemented, I believe, is that there are better ways to store regenerative energy. It's easier to store the energy back into the battery rather than in a separate supercapacitor. The battery in an electric vehicle is large enough (and therefore has a low enough internal resistance) that it will accept and store the short burst of regen energy efficiently. Not as efficiently as a supercapacitor, perhaps, but the losses from the additional circuit required to transfer energy in and out of the supercapacitor reduce that advantage. For every dollar spent in the added circuit and the supercapacitor, you could be spending that dollar on a larger battery whose charge will last longer.